# Form elements never get enabled after getting disabled in firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, element

I came through kind of a strange problem in my application. When the user clicks the refresh button in the application, the form elements get disabled but never get enabled. This only happens sometimes, and in firefox only. Following is the javascript code snippet that's used to disable the form elements.

```
util.Document.setDisabledOnFormElements = function(disabled, baseElement) {
  if (util.Browser.is(util.Browser.IE)) {
    //disabled property is inherited in ie.
    baseElement.disabled = disabled;
  } else {
    var dels = util.Document.DISABLEABLE_FORM_ELEMENTS;
    var els;
    for (var h = 0, hLength = dels.length; h < hLength; h++) {
      //disabled property is not inherited, so have to set for disableable elements explicitly.
      els = baseElement.getElementsByTagName(dels[h]);
      for (var j = 0, jLength = els.length; j < jLength; j++) {
        els[j].disabled = disabled;
        els[j] = null;
      }
      els = null;
    }
    dels = null;
  }
};
```

This setDisabledOnFormElements function is called by a for loop and all the elements in the form is given as parameters. And the 'disabled' parameter is a boolean object. It tells whether to disable the elements or enable the elements.

In IE and Chrome this works really fine. But in FF form elements never get enabled after clicking the refresh button(This is not the browser's refresh button). Does anyone know the problem here?

Comment: "This is not the browser's refresh button" — What is it then?

Comment: This is a button that I use in my app.

Comment: Presumably there is some code relating to it…

Comment: At present you question is essentially "This is how I disable things. When I run *some other code* to enable things, it doesn't work in some browsers". We can't tell you why the other code doesn't work because we can't see it!

Comment: @Quentin : This is the same code that I use to enable things also..Only difference is the boolean value of the 'disabled' parameter is different.

Comment: Different in exactly what way? What else does the code do? Does it work if your refresh function does *nothing* except call the function you've provided? What errors does the browser report?

Comment: Difference is that when you want to disable the elements, it sets the disabled parameter as false. Otherwise u set it as true. And yes. it works if my refresh function does nothing except call the function I have provided. And there are no erros. AND it works sometimes also. Sometimes it doesn't.